# Height of bars in barh matplotlib (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a horizontal bar char using the library matplotlib (python). I noticed that depending on the number of categories in y-axis, the height of the bars changes.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


plt.rcdefaults()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Example data
people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error = np.random.rand(len(people))

ax.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
ax.set_xlabel('Performance')
ax.set_title('How fast do you want to go today?')

plt.show()
```

The y-axis has the categories 'Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim' and 'Jim'. If I change the tuple "people" to ('Tom', 'Dick'), the height of my horizontal bars change drastically. I tried to set the parameter 'height' (ax.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center', height = 0.8)), but it does not work.

Does anyone know how to solve this situation ?

Comment: The height of the bar stays the same. What you see is a result of the span of your y-axis. In the first case, it is from 0-4, in the second it is 0-1.

Comment: @Sheldore, thank you for clarifying it for me!  I add 'ax.set_ylim([-0.65,4.65])' and now it is working.